# Make the Intellisense nullability warning conditional, similar to Dictionary<string, string>.TryGetValue(...)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ide, intellisense, nullability

In Visual Studio, Intellisense is smart enough to know that the 'out' variable `value` in `Dictionary<string, string>.TryGetValue(string key, out string value)` is **not** `null` if the method returns `true`:

[image]

I'm trying to emulate this with the following example, but I don't know what to do. How can I give Intellisense the hint that the out variable `result` in `TryGetString()` will **not** be `null` if the method returns `true`?

**Note: I still want the nullability check to appear when the TryGetString() method returns false, the same way it works with `Dictionary<string, string>.TryGetValue(string key, out string value)`**

```
public class TestClass
{
    private int Number = 3;
    private bool TryGetString(out string? result)
    {
        // 'result' is null if this method returns 'false'
        if (Number > -1)
        {
            result = Number.ToString();
            return true;
        }
        result = null;
        return false;
    }
    public void Init()
    {
        if (TryGetString(out var result))
        {
            string a = result; // Visual Studio gives a null warning here,
                               // even though 'result' is not null inside
                               // this code block.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of attributes in the `System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis` namespace that can be used to provide information to the compiler's code analyzer.

To indicate that an `out` parameter is not *null* when the return value is *true*, use the [`[NotNullWhen]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.notnullwhenattribute) attribute:

```
private bool TryGetString([NotNullWhen(returnValue: true)] out string? result)
```

Comment: To complete the response you may use both attributes
```private bool TryGetString([NotNullWhen(true)] [MaybeNullWhen(false)] out string? result)```

Comment: @Treziac, \[MaybeNullWhen\] would be redundant here. `string?` is a nullable reference type, which also means `string?` is by nature "maybe null"...

Comment: Nevermind, mixing with an other case, sorry